# Jquery inArray not working?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove the element ID a user selects from an array using `.splice` and `.inArray`, but the `inArray` doesn't seem to recognize the variable I'm saving the element ID in.

I've tried alerting remove and it definitely equals a number in the array, and if I enter the value of remove into `inArray` it works, but for some reason it's not converting the variable to a number when I plug the variable into `inArray`. Can anyone help?

```
input.push($(this).attr("id"));
var remove = input[input.length-1];
possible.splice($.inArray(remove, possible),1);
```

Comment: past complete code

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a number since the comparison between values is strict in [`jQuery.inArray`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method (i.e, which checks the type).

```
var remove = Number(input[input.length-1]);
```